# How to use PHPExcel correctly with Symfony 2

Tags: symfony, configuration, phpexcel

I need to use [`PHPExcel`](http://www.phpexcel.net/) with a `Symfony2` project. Anyone know how to set up the project correctly to use the library? Should i put it in the vendor directory? What should be changed in the configuration files etc?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using composer to manage your project, you can just change the composer.json file:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "": "src/",
        "": "vendor/phpoffice/phpexcel/Classes/"
    },
    "classmap": [
        "app/AppKernel.php",
        "app/AppCache.php"
    ]
},
```

Then add

```
use PHPExcel;
use PHPExcel_IOFactory;
```

to your controller file, and you can use the PHPExcel like this:

```
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Yep, this is the modern way. In 2011 things were a bit different :)

Answer (score 14):

Actually, to do it right you need to follow next steps:

- Edit your `deps` file and add dependency from the `PHPExcel`

> ```
> [PHPExcel]
> git=http://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel.git
> target=/phpexcel
> version=origin/master
> ```

- Run `php bin/vendors install` in order to install all missing dependencies (`PHPExcel` in our case)
- Update prefixes section in `app/autoload.php`:

> ```
> $loader->registerPrefixes(array(
>     // ...
>     'PHPExcel'         => __DIR__.'/../vendor/phpexcel/Classes',
> ));
> ```

- Done. Now, you can use it in your bundle's controller (code based on `PHPExcel` example from `Tests/01simple-download-xls.php`):

```php
<?php
namespace Demo\MyBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use PHPExcel;
use PHPExcel_IOFactory;

class DemoController extends Controller
{
   public function demoAction()
   { 
       $response = new Response();

       // Create new PHPExcel object
       $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();

       // Set document properties
       $objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setCreator("Me")
                   ->setLastModifiedBy("Someone")
                   ->setTitle("My first demo")
                   ->setSubject("Demo Document");
       // Add some data
       $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
                   ->setCellValue('A1', 'Hello')
                   ->setCellValue('B2', 'world!')
                   ->setCellValue('C1', 'Hello')
                   ->setCellValue('D2', 'world!');
       // Set active sheet index to the first sheet
       $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);

       // Redirect output to a client’s web browser (Excel5)
       $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/vnd.ms-excel');
       $response->headers->set('Content-Disposition', 'attachment;filename="demo.xls"');
       $response->headers->set('Cache-Control', 'max-age=0');
       $response->prepare();
       $response->sendHeaders();
       $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');
       $objWriter->save('php://output');
       exit();
   }
}
```

Comment: just add  `$response = new Response();` at the beginning of the function and include `use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;`

Comment: I would never use "new" operator in Symfony2 controller as basically - you are saying - I will never unit test this controller, nor I'm giving my co-workers giving a chance to test this. This will work, but it's a bad, bad practice

Comment: @alchemication Can you provide the best practice solution?

Comment: @gakhov Sure, sorry, my bad;) Wrap PHPExcel in a service class and the use `$this->get('my.phpexcel_service')` in the controller to access that service. Then you can inject this service to other services as well...and so on... and all is easy to test/mock. Hope it helped at least a bit.

Comment: @gakhov Worth a read (even a few times): [Symfony2 Services Docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html)

Answer (score 11):

1. Copy the library to your vendors directory.
2. Configure autoloader in your bootstrap file:

   ```
   $loader->registerPrefixes(array(
       // Swift, Twig etc.
       'PHPExcel' => __DIR__ . '/../vendor/phpexcel/lib/PHPExcel'
   ));
   ```
3. That's all.

Comment: I have the same problem, could you explain your solution a bit more? If I try to initialize the PHPExcel class in my controller, I get a "class not found"...

Comment: Thank you - but how can I init the PHPExcel class in my controller - is a "new PHPExcel" sufficient or do I have to use a namespace?

Comment: PHPExcel doesn't support namespaces, it's defined in global namespace. Use `\PHPExcel`.

Comment: Someday (hopefully) PHPExcel will be able to drop support for PHP 5.2 and set PHP5.3 as a minimum version, and then we will be able to use namespaces; but with over 50% of the userbase still running 5.2 servers we can't make the change yet :(

Answer (score 10):

actually the best solution is to use https://github.com/liuggio/ExcelBundle.
I tried to use @Crozin's solution but I was still getting an error about IOFactory::createWriter.
Hope this helps,
Simone

Answer (score 7):

As of Symfony 2.3, you can now do this:

```
...
"require": {
    ...
    "phpoffice/phpexcel": "dev-master"
    ...
},
...
```

Then just run `composer update` and dependencies will resolve automatically.

Or you can do `composer require phpoffice/phpexcel:dev-master` if you don't want to mess with the `composer.json` file.

Answer (score 2):

With composer (since Symfony2.1) it's really easy, you only have to modify the `composer.json`.
You don't need to register the namespace anymore!

Only two things, to notice:

1. refer to github tags, I only found a soltion with the `package` type
2. when changing something in the composer.json related to the class autoloading stuff, you have to remove the whole directory in the `vendor` dir

Here is the related link: [use PHPExcel with composer and Symfony2.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16196851/use-phpexcel-with-composer-and-symfony2-2/16197243)