# How I can install the PHPExcel library in laravel?

Tags: php, excel, laravel, laravel-4

I was considering to download the library from its home page (http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Examples) but also do not know what folder should I place it. How I can install?

Comment: This should help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16196851/use-phpexcel-with-composer-and-symfony2-2

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**You should use composer:**  Add `"phpexcel/phpexcel": "dev-master"` to your `composer.json`

```
"require": {
    "phpexcel/phpexcel": "dev-master"
}
```

Then execute `composer update`. So you can use it as normal:

```
public function import($path){

    $objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($path);
    $objWorksheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();
    $highestRow = $objWorksheet->getHighestRow();
    for ($row = 1; $row <= $highestRow; ++$row) {
         var_dump($objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(1, $row));
    }

}
```

Comment: Excelent answer but in my case is ``laravel/framework": "4.1.*,`` because I use 4.1 version

Comment: Do you have a tutorial on how to export a excel?

Comment: Sorry I don't have, but you can download documentation (http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/releases/view/119187), there are a lot of examples for everything you need. Also, check online documentation (https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/wiki/User%20Documentation)

Comment: What is means "$path"?

Comment: To future readers: replace `phpexcel/phpexcel` to `phpoffice/phpexcel` as first library mark as deprecated

Comment: phpexcel is no longer maintained and being developed. phpoffice/phpSpreadsheet looks to be the replacement.

Answer (score 14):

For install PhpExcel in laravel 5.

Please visit this link for pakage -https://packagist.org/packages/phpoffice/phpexcel.

Please follow the instruction --

1:- Add `"phpoffice/phpexcel": "dev-master"` to your composer.json.

2:- execute `"composer update"` on terminal.

3:- Open the file "/vendor/composer/autoload_namespaces.php". Paste the below line in the file.

```
'PHPExcel' => array($vendorDir . '/phpoffice/phpexcel/Classes'),
```

4:- Now you can use PHPEXCEL library in your controllers or middleware or library.

```
use PHPExcel; 
use PHPExcel_IOFactory;
```

Comment: step 3 sometimes is optional, as composer himself add that line to te namespace file

Comment: Some great steps but phpexcel is no longer maintained and being developed. phpoffice/phpSpreadsheet looks to be the replacement.

Answer (score 9):

There's actually a neat new PHPExcel library specifically made for Laravel. Easy installation and it looks easy to use (I'm unaffiliated). https://laravel-excel.com/

Comment: Only just released as well, really useful for using PHPExcel from within Laravel

Answer (score 4):

If you are using **Laravel 5**. It is very easy.

check [this link](http://www.maatwebsite.nl/laravel-excel/docs/getting-started) for configuration

you may need to type in the following command to proceed with the package download

> composer require maatwebsite/excel

check [this link](http://www.maatwebsite.nl/laravel-excel/docs/export) for usage

my might want to look at my example code:

```
public function testexcel(){

    Excel::create('testfile', function($excel) {
        // Set the title
        $excel->setTitle('no title');
        $excel->setCreator('no no creator')->setCompany('no company');
        $excel->setDescription('report file');

        $excel->sheet('sheet1', function($sheet) {
            $data = array(
                array('header1', 'header2','header3','header4','header5','header6','header7'),
                array('data1', 'data2', 300, 400, 500, 0, 100),
                array('data1', 'data2', 300, 400, 500, 0, 100),
                array('data1', 'data2', 300, 400, 500, 0, 100),
                array('data1', 'data2', 300, 400, 500, 0, 100),
                array('data1', 'data2', 300, 400, 500, 0, 100),
                array('data1', 'data2', 300, 400, 500, 0, 100)
            );
            $sheet->fromArray($data, null, 'A1', false, false);
            $sheet->cells('A1:G1', function($cells) {
            $cells->setBackground('#AAAAFF');

            });
        });
    })->download('xlsx');
}
```

Comment: You offer Laravel-Excel, which is build based on PHP-Excel.my question is does it has PHP-Excel functionality ?

Answer (score 2):

For future readers:

PHPExcell is **no more maintained**. Rather use:

https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet
http://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/develop/#installation

> Because all efforts have shifted to PhpSpreadsheet, PHPExcel will no longer be maintained. All contributions for PHPExcel, patches and new features, should target PhpSpreadsheet develop branch.